# Shiny App Issue, ShinyDirButton is unresponsive

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

This code should produce a pop up that allows Directory Selection for a Shiny App.

However, when I run the code the button appears but is unresponsive in both the R-studio viewer and when run in a web-browser.

Does the code work for you? Is there anything that I am not doing right?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyDirButton('folder', 'Select a folder', 'Please select a folder', FALSE)
)
server <- function(input, output){
  volumes = getVolumes() # this makes the directory at the base of your computer.
  observe({
    shinyDirChoose(input, 'folder', roots=volumes, filetypes=c('', 'txt'))
    print(input$folder)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found a different function that works,  choose.dir().

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

ui <- fluidPage( 
actionButton("dir", 'select a folder'),  
textOutput("wd") #display working directory 
)

server <- function(input, output) { 
observeEvent(input$dir, {   
setwd(choose.dir("c:/")) #selecting a directory   
output$wd <- renderText(getwd())})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```